# Expected primary-expression before ‘int map iterator declaration

Tags: c++, dictionary, compilation, const-iterator

I dont know why im getting this error:

```
src/Cronologia.cpp: In member function ‘void Cronologia::recuento()’:
src/Cronologia.cpp:106:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     map<int,EventoHistorico> ::const_iterator itm;
         ^
src/Cronologia.cpp:106:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

So my iterator its not being declared, and I get more error of no declaration.

Here is my code:

```
void Cronologia::recuento()
{
    int map = cronologias.size();
    cout << "Numero de anios: " << map << endl;
    map<int,EventoHistorico> ::const_iterator itm;
    for(itm=cronologias.begin();itm!=cronologias.end();++itm)
    {
            cout << "Anio: " << (*itm).first;
            cout << "Numero de eventos: " << (*itm).second.size() << endl;
    }
}
```

Its weird because Im declaring the same thing in other function, and getting no errors:

```
Cronologia Cronologia::filtrarIntervalo(int inf, int sup)
{
    Cronologia result;
    map<int,EventoHistorico>::const_iterator itinf, itsup;
    itinf = cronologias.find(inf);
    itsup = cronologias.find(sup);
}
```

Comment: `int map = cronologias.size();` ?

Comment: This is why [`using namesapce std;` is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: There im getting the size of a map

Comment: @NathanOliver any suggestion?

Comment: You get the size of the map, and assign it to what variable?

Comment: Like tha answers say, don't use `using namesapce std;` and instead use `std::` everywhere.  Its only 5 more characters.

Comment: @Rusillo Have you tried changing the name of that variable to something else than a container's name ?